# Logging into Apache password-protected file using Keychain

Tags: ios, apache, keychain

I setup a password-protected file on my server domain.

When I access it through IOS 14.8 and Safari on my iPhone SE. A window pops up to enter my user name and password. After I do that, Safari doesn't offer to save it in Keychain. (The usual response from Safari is to ask.)

I went to the setting/passwords on my iPhone and explicitly entered the URL, username, and password. Then when I go to access my web site, I can bring Keychain up, but it lists all the logons in Keychain, not just the one that match the URL.

I have to search through my entire list of logons and select the appropriate one to use. For other  website logons, Keychain/Safari bring up only the logon matching the URL.

I've tried using Opera/Chrome and experienced the same problem.

I created a mock logon form on an HTML file. Safari/Keychain responds properly to this form, providing me only the Keychain logon info for the specific website.

I've checked with the server provider and they didn't have any answers. I believe the server uses Apache since it uses .htaccess and .htpasswrd to protect the file.

Does anybody have any answers or insight into this issue?